# Instagram API in R - Deprecated - Need to use graph.facebook.com

Tags: r, api, facebook-graph-api, instagram, httr

I am simply looking to get the follower count for specific users on instagram.

I have been spending several hours looking into this and here are my findings:

Instagram's API has been deprecated where you cannot collect instagram user info besides yourself.

This means that the `instaR` package will not help anymore for this task.

I think the new API is through `graph.facebook.com`.

I created a token through the tools section in the graph.facebook.com API and also retrieved a client id and secret: 
[image]

From here:

```
##With Facebook Graph API for Instagram Posts
client_id <- "XXXXXXX"
client_secret <- "XXXXXXXXXXXX"

token <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

HeaderValue = paste0('Bearer ', token)

response = POST(
  'https://graph.facebook.com/token',
  accept_json(),
  authenticate(client_id, client_secret),
  body = list(grant_type = 'client_credentials'),
  encode = 'form',
  verbose()
)

instaFeaturesURL <- paste("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/users/search?q=", username,"&access_token=",token,sep="")
getinstaFeatures <- GET(instaFeaturesURL, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))
instaFeatures <- jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(content(getinstaFeatures)))
instaFeatures$error

$`message`
[1] "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: users"

$type
[1] "OAuthException"

$code
[1] 803

$fbtrace_id
[1] "ET29axa/P69"
```

Has anyone tried doing this? I don't even know where to access instagram from the Facebook API with this new change. Definitely need some help haha.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Edit: Based on comments:

I tried using the the FBinsightsR package and below was my output after doing the following:

```
FBinsightsR::fbins_insta(start_date = '2019-01-01', until_date = '2019-01-31', time_period = "day", token, insta_account = 'therock')
```

`-> GET /v3.2/therock/insights? 
metric=reach%2C%20impressions%2C%20follower_count%2C%20profile_views%2C%20website_clicks&period=day&access_token=EAAbhcJILvJwBACWPKQoGGmaDSfUlFjBp7ZCfUuw0hiyk43rDflBw4Bz2VeXjSI1CHWneAGsrXgxZCrRKdcsYrWEQOBARiwZBjF1ztQKhZC1GyNuQ46gWB3XpBv3Pi3StJiqZB7ypI01R8CP3Tqkjh5mUZCBRojNuLIGmAGSyuxrD1HCGUMT0jVMUO8ebnWPw9IaPgzg70PgAZDZD&since=2019-01-01&until=2019-01-31 HTTP/1.1
-> Host: graph.facebook.com
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.59.0 r-curl/3.2 httr/1.4.0
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
<- Vary: Accept-Encoding
<- Content-Encoding: gzip
<- x-app-usage: {"call_count":2,"total_cputime":0,"total_time":0}
<- WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'therock' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"
<- Content-Type: application/json
<- facebook-api-version: v3.2
<- x-fb-rev: 4735306
<- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
<- Cache-Control: no-store
<- x-fb-trace-id: EXOKV33fR8G
<- Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
<- Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload
<- Pragma: no-cache
<- X-FB-Debug: ckCuGe6IKtUH4t62uJCJncpUfvMfZO0zbfWXsCyLCTUo7DuqOGDDJHhQRbW2/noaTNRqiUBFfY9sUGRBDH0MnA==
<- Date: Mon, 04 Feb 2019 15:19:03 GMT
<- Connection: keep-alive
<- Content-Length: 274
<- 
Error:`.x`is empty, and no`.init`supplied`

Comment: the URL I use is : `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/xxxxxxx/insights"` - where the x's represent the instagram ID, so it's still through the general Facebook API. I wrote my own package for this - it's called `FBinsightsR` and it's on GitHub.  The metrics pulled are reach, impressions, follower count, profile views and website clicks.

Comment: I should say - I've never had to use client secret - a page access token works just fine so long as you have an app with permissions issued through business manager or such.

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely making more sense. I'm thinking this may be a token issue. @nycrefugee Based on this error, is that what you think this is?

Comment: also would you mind sending me an email? It would be great to hop on a call to discuss this more! Willing to pay a consulting fee if needed. My email is nickknauer1@gmail.com

Comment: Or can you please provide me a working insta account that has worked for you in the past? Just trying to figure out what the issue may be